# Using completion handler together with DispatchQueue

Tags: swift, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch, nsurlsession, completionhandler

I have learned that concurrent `DispatchQueue` allows the code inside it to return immediately, hence not blocking the calling thread. This is usually used with background tasks loading large data.

I have also learned that completion handler (for example, in `URLSession` ) allows the code inside handler to be executed after some task finishes.

My question is: does it mean that concurrent dispatch queue and completion handler have overlapping purpose? If I already used completion handler, there is no need to wrap it with a concurrent dispatch queue?

For example, below is a time-consuming data loading task using URLSession, is it a good idea to wrap it with a concurrent dispatch queue?

```
URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default).dataTask(with: propertiesRequest) { data, response, error in
        // print("within dataTask: data: \(data), response: \(response), error: \(error)")
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        } else if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                print("success: property task request")


                do {

                    handler(responseDict, nil) // This is a function supplied by caller

                } catch let error as NSError {
                    handler(nil, error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unrelated, I'd make sure you call your completion handler if `error` was not nil or if the status code was not 200. Your caller undoubtedly wants to know when the request finished, whether successful or not.

Comment: @Rob I agree. will adopt this in my project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to use Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) dispatch queues in conjunction with time-consuming `URLSession` request.

You'd might use GCD inside the `dataTask` completion handler closure if:

1. If you are doing something inside the closure is, itself, very time consuming (e.g. processing very complicated request) and you don't want to tie up the serial operation queue that `URLSession` uses for processing its completion handlers (and delegate method). This does not appear to be the issue here (e.g. parsing JSON responses is generally quick enough we don't have to worry about this), but just FYI. Or,
2. If, when you're done parsing the response of `dataTask`, if you want to update some model object or update the UI. You want to do those on the main queue.

   For example, if your request was returning a bunch of objects to show in some tableview, you'd dispatch the update of the model and the UI to the main queue:

   ```
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
       self.objects = ...
       self.tableView.reloadData()
   }
   ```

But you don't have to worry about the time-consuming `URLSession` request, itself. That already happens asynchronously, so you don't have to dispatch that to a background queue.

Answer (score 4):

The `DispatchQueue` and the completion handler do not overlap but rather can be used as a seamless solution for handling queues. The data loading task in `URLSession` is already asynchronous and thus have no need to be wrapped in a `DispatchQueue`.

`DispatchQueue` - assigning tasks to a specific thread for better performance (global queue) / user experience (main queue).

Completion Handlers - guarantees certain code will run when the task has been completed. However, the execution is on the current thread unless explicitly stated otherwise.

[image: example]

For example, calling on method A which employs `DispatchQueue.global.async` will queue the task on the global queue, freeing the main queue for more important (UI) tasks. After some time, the task would have been completed and usually, we would want to do something with the data. If it is UI related, we definitely want to call on `DispatchQueue.main.async` to update the screen with info or if it is trivial, no calls need to be made and vanilla code would suffice.